# changing pptp client default port

Tags: pptp

I am trying to setup PPTP connections to 2 separate servers through a firewall. No problem for one server, just port forwarded ports 47 and 1723 on through to server 1.

To connect to server 2 my strategy is to forward two different ports (not 47 and 1723) to the standard ports on server 2.

My question is how do I initiate a PPTP connection on the client side to the alternate ports for server 2? This question was answered here on Jan 1, 2012 by user1125087, but I don't understand the answer provided. What are "mangling rules"?

**As for the client side use mangling rules to get around the issue if there isn't an option (I don't use the software personally) or else modify/re-compile.**

I use Mac Linux AND windows as clients so I really need solutions for them all. Again, this is for the client side NOT SERVER side.

I'm beginning to wonder if this is possible on Mac & Windows. On Linux I could probably find something and recompile it for the alternate ports, but that too much effort.

I'm trying to create redundant, fault tolerant access. I spent 45 minutes trying to do this with OpenVPN but was not able to get that working.

Comment: PPTP doesn't use "port 47". It uses *protocol* 47-- GRE. Big difference.

Comment: Exactly - what @EvanAnderson said. Which is also the reason having multiple PPTP clients behind a single NAT is problematic.